# Reading a Prolific serial device in Java on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: java, linux, serial-port, usb, rxtx

I am developing a Java application that takes input from a device that uses a Serial port. The device in question is a barcode scanner that is connected to a Prolific PL2303 USB adapter. I believe the driver for that adapter is present, as you can see this line when running a lsusb command:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
```

I have installed the java RXTX 64 bit library. I have the .so files under /usr/lib/jni and, in my eclipse project, I point to that as my Native Library Location. I have placed the RXTXComm.jar inside a lib directory in my project and successfully loaded it in my application.

I can see the /dev/ttyUSB0 device listed. I have modified its permissions with a chmod 777 command to be safe. I also added my user to the dialout group.

With that, and setting the correct parameters (baud rate, parity, stopbits and databits) will I be able to serial read from /dev/ttyUSB0? I have tried writing a simple application to accomplish this. In one class I connect the port with the following code:

```
    public void connect(String portName) throws Exception {
    CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
    if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
        System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
    } else {
        CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(), 2000);
        listener.setEntrada(commPort.getInputStream());
        if (commPort instanceof SerialPort) {
            SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);
            serialPort.addEventListener(listener);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error. Not a serial Port");
        }
    }
```

The listener is Spring injected and implements SerialPortEventListener. However, when I use the scanner, the overriden serialEvent(SerialPortEvent ev) method is never called.

What am I missing? Do I have to map the device to a ttyS* port to read from it?

*** EDIT *** 
Seems I had forgotten to add a notification to the listener, solved by adding "serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);" after adding the event listener.

However, now when reading from the inputStream I got the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3b82aee462, pid=12531, tid=139893572269824
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_66-b17) (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.66-b17 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [librxtxSerial.so+0x6462]  read_byte_array+0x52
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/zanni/workspace/BarcodeComms/hs_err_pid12531.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Is this an issue with the library?

Comment: Observation: I get the input from the scanner correctly when using minicom.

Comment: So I know that in some environments garbage collection in the JVM can interrupt data streams from Serial devices.

Comment: I really don't think this is a GC issue. The very first read call in the stream blocks. I also get the log message "Experimental:  JNI_OnLoad called.".